# How to separate Jekyll posts into two different folders?

Tags: jekyll

I have a `_posts` folder and I just want a simple way to separate the posts in the folder into two different folders, and not have any permalink changes, for purely organizational reasons.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just create subdirectories in your `_posts` directory; the subdirectories will be ignored when Jekyll generates permalinks.

Comment: Is there a way to add documents to this subdirectory and find it back when the website is built ?

Comment: Not anymore!  Broken in jekyll 2.2.0.  Trying to get this functionality reinstated over here because it was awesome: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/2633#issuecomment-51151555


@rooofl Create a plain directory outside of your `./_posts` folder and put another `_posts` folder in that new folder.  The name of this new folder sets the category of any posts in this new `./category/_posts` folder and you can access that just as if you set the category in the front-matter.

Comment: @Bret: I think this must have just been a code blip. I'm on 3.0.1 and subdirectories in the `_post` folder seem fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this to my `_posts` folder because I have over 200 files. I decided to create folders that represent each year I have a posts for. Doing this though, broke `post_url`. The error is something like as follows when you run `jekyll build`

> Liquid Exception: Could not find post "blah-blah" in tag 'post_url'. Make sure the post exists and the name is correct. in _posts/2007/blah-blah.md

I had to go back in and where ever I used `post_url`, I had to add `/year/` in front of each post url links.

https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1714#issuecomment-28167702