# How to use :author in jekyll permalink structure for github pages

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have a jekyll/ruby hosted blog on github pages, within which I would like user submitted content.

In the front matter of each markdown file I would like users to be able to state their username:

```
 ---
 title: some title
 author: bobby-tables
 ---
```

I would then like to use this in the generation of the permalink to the post
`/:author/:title/` i have this set in my `_config.yml` file.

But actually `:author` is visible in the url and seems to be ignored/unconverted

I know this works with `:categories` but this is not semantically correct and is confusing for  some bloggers and novice users.

Is there a way to use `:author` ?

The site is hosted on github pages so i cannot use any plugins, as i cannot generate the  `_site` locally for each update from my home machine.

I have reviewed the documentation at jeykllrb.com but cannot see `:author` being used/mentioned especially within template tags.

It is also not practical to have `permalinks: name/title` in the front matter for each markdown file either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a subfolder solution such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998729/how-to-separate-jekyll-posts-into-two-different-folders?rq=1 would be suitable if, IF it could be used as a variable in the permalink and in listing 'authors' on another page.

Comment: I've made a [jekyll plug-in](https://gist.github.com/peey/897e8ed33e412fdfe0fcacf002acc150) for this which supports any custom variables at all, based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17206081/1412255)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just done some tests and I can't get any custom variables in the front matter to be interpreted as part of the permalink.

Looking through the code, what I can understand (still new to ruby) it is only accepting the ones listed here http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

At the moment, depending on your workflow categories or tags seem like the only option as you can use plugins. If categories does not make sense semantically then perhaps use tag and explain that they are tagging themselves in the posts that they have written.